# Localization for \date command

Tags: date, datetime2

How can I apply localization for the `\date` command? For now it seems to just display an arbitrary string.

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{me}
\date{bla bla bla}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

How can I specify a date in some format? I used datetime2 `\date{\DTMdate{2020}{9}{7}}` but it gives me compilation error: `Paragraph ended before \@dtm@parsedate was complete.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to read [the documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf)

You would write instead

```
\date{\DTMdate{2020-9-7}}
```

You will, of course need to load the `datetime2` package with

```
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
```

and use the appropriate `babel` options to select your language.

Comment: It does not seem to reflect my `babel`/`polyglossia` configuration. Furthermore, `2020-40-40` also works, which is weird.

Comment: It doesn't seem to really have any validation in it. There is a limited set of languages which are supported by datetime2. You can look at an existing `.ldf` file for a model of how to add in a missing language.